# Dissector table doesn't exist while registering subdissector for ZMTP

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to create an "out-of-tree" dissector plugin for my protocol:

- My protocol messages are encapsulated into ZMTP frames, so I'm using [this Lua dissector](https://github.com/whitequark/zmtp-wireshark).
- Regarding subdissectors, we can read [the following in its documentation](https://github.com/whitequark/zmtp-wireshark#subdissectors):

```lua
-- Register a subdissector "my_subdissector" to the ZMTP protocol table for TCP port 1234
local zmtp = DissectorTable.get("zmtp.protocol")
zmtp:add(1234, my_subdissector_proto)
-- Register the ZMTP dissector as the default for that TCP port (so no "decode as" is needed)
local zmtp_dissector = Dissector.get("zmtp")
local tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
tcp_table:add(1234, zmtp_dissector)
```

So I guess basically it provides a table called `zmtp.protocol` in which I need to register my own dissector.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <config.h>
#include <epan/packet.h>

namespace impl
{

static int proto = -1;
static dissector_handle_t handle;

static int dissect(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo _U_, proto_tree *tree, void *data _U_)
{
    proto_tree_add_protocol_format(tree, proto, tvb, 0, -1, "This is Toto, a Wireshark dissector plugin prototype");
    return tvb_captured_length(tvb);
}

static void proto_register()
{
    proto = proto_register_protocol("Toto protocol", "Toto", "toto");
    handle = create_dissector_handle(&dissect, proto);
}

static void plugin_reg_handoff()
{
    dissector_add_uint("zmtp.protocol", 23456, handle);
}

}

extern "C"
{
    char plugin_version[] = "0.0.1";
    int plugin_want_major = VERSION_MAJOR;
    int plugin_want_minor = VERSION_MINOR;

    void plugin_register()
    {
        static proto_plugin plug;

        plug.register_protoinfo = impl::proto_register;
        plug.register_handoff = impl::plugin_reg_handoff;
        proto_register_plugin(&plug);
    }
}
```

When I launch Wireshark from the command line, I get the following message:

```
OOPS: dissector table "zmtp.protocol" doesn't exist
Protocol being registered is "Toto protocol"
```

Both plugins seem to be correctly registered by Wireshark when I look at `Help > About Wireshark > Plugins`. Plus I named them so that the Lua dissector appears before mine in the list.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

The Lua dissector seems to be working fine, I can `Decode As... > ZMTP` and it does a great job.

Comment: Since I'm not the one who provided the answer to this same question over at ask.wireshark.com, I'll just supply the link to that question and the answer given by Guy Harris in case anyone else comes searching for the same thing on this site: https://ask.wireshark.org/question/32219/dissector-table-doesnt-exist-while-registering-subdissector-for-zmtp/